# Resolve component only if lifetime matches

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

Wireup example:

```
// Module 1
builder.Register(ctx => new ServiceImpl1())
       .As<ISomeSubService>()
       .SingleInstance();

// Module 2
builder.Register(ctx => new MyComponent(ctx.Resolve<ISomeSubService>()))
       .As<IComponent>()
       .SingleInstance();
```

This is a working but dangerous solution: if, at a later point, someone refactors module 1 and decides to use `ServiceImpl2` (which might not be SingleInstance-registrable anymore), module 2 would silently introduce a bug.

Is there any possibility that the resolution of `IComponent` fails, if the resolution of the ctor argument `ISomeSubService` has not at least the same lifetime duration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There's no way in Autofac to enforce that a child dependency's lifetime is equal to the consuming component's.**

If you think about it, in many cases that may not actually be a bug.

Say, for example, I have a global logger. I might register it as a `SingleInstance` because it can be shared.

```
builder.RegisterType<MyLogger>()
       .As<ILogger>()
       .SingleInstance();
```

I may then have an MVC controller that needs the logger. It only lives for one request.

```
builder.RegisterType<MyController>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

**That's OK.** The logger is supposed to be shared across things, so having a different lifetime is just fine.

**Now switch it around** - say you have a repository that makes calls to get localized resources from a database. It's cheap to create and it gets registered `InstancePerDependency`.

```
builder.RegisterType<MyResourceRepository>()
       .As<IResourceRepository>();
       .InstancePerDependency();
```

You also have a display widget in a Windows Forms app that shows some localized data but it lives for the lifetime of the app - it's `SingleInstance`.

```
builder.RegisterType<MyWidget>()
       .SingleInstance();
```

It will grab a copy of the resource repository when it's constructed and that resource repository instance will hold it for the whole app lifetime. **That's not necessarily a bug.** In many cases, that may actually be just fine.

**Instead of trying to enforce things across modules, let objects control their own lifetimes** and don't worry so much about it. Register things with the lifetime scope they should have.

If you are worried that a singleton component may try to grab a service that it shouldn't keep alive for the whole application, **[use the `Func<T>` relationship](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#dynamic-instantiation-func-b) inside the singleton object to auto-resolve a factory** and call the function to get the service instead of hanging onto it.

```
public class A
{
  Func<B> _b;

  public A(Func<B> b) { _b = b; }

  public void M()
  {
    var b = _b();
    b.DoSomething();
  }
}
```

You may also be able to make use of [the other implicit relationship types](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html) to help deal with issues like this. For example, if you need to dispose of the object when you're done with it, you may want a `Func<Owned<T>>` so you can control disposal, too.

Comment: When you say "register things with the lifetime scope they should have", what strategy would you suggest if the lifetime doesn't really matter?

Previously, my team used to prefer `SingleInstance` if the component supported it, even if singleton behavior was not _required_. Rationale: It didn't seem necessary to recreate the component for every dependent.
Now, we've decided to use `InstancePerDependency` instead in such cases since it avoids the subtle coupling between different registrations that might too easily lead to bugs.

Comment: Example: Stateless service `A` depends on abstraction `IB`. Singleton `B` implements `IB`. There is no need to register `A` as a `SingleInstance`. We used to prefer registering `A` as `SingleInstance` (which required us to keep the registration of `B` in mind), now we prefer `InstancePerDependency` (which works no matter what implementation of `IB` we use and how `B` is registered).
Do you consider this a good strategy or are there other catches we're now missing?

Comment: There is no "rule of thumb" here. It truly depends on the implementation - the thing you're registering. In general what you describe is fine. When you think about the scope for a component, think about _that component_ rather than its dependencies. Then if you find a component may hold something too long or you want to be resource-conscious, use the relationships like `Func`. I can think of times where I have dependencies that change per environment - `IA` is implemented by `A1` in one deployment but `A2` in another and they each have different lifetimes. Just use what the component needs.